# пишем на php cli

Tags: php

Добрый вечер.

Часто приходится писать скрипты на php (одноразовые), перенос данных с одного сайта на другой, парсинг и т.д. Выполнения скрипта может занимать 30-100 мин.
Естественно запуская скрипт через обычный браузер, обращаясь через http к скрипту, то сервер после некоторого времени (30, 60, 120) сек, возвращает 503, разрывает соединение. Разные настройки сервера не помогают.

Читал, что помогают в таких случаях, писать php скрипты под консоль. Так называемый php cli.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне это сделать?
Предположим у меня есть хостинг со скриптами, мои дальнейшие действия?
Не могу разобраться, где открыть эту консоль и т.д. 
Насколько я понял, php cli это просто такой режим запуска интерпретатора, с некоторыми параметрами.

Comment: по поводу 503. Скорее всего, всё от того, что браузер не получает никакой информации. у них есть свои ограничения на время получения ответа.если на ajax можно задать время ожидания то с пхп нужно делать что-то на сервере. когда писал парсеры я их обманывал(браузеры), отдавая браузеру хоть что-то. (к примеру print '';\flush()) тем самым браузер получает вывод и не закрывает соединение. так же не забываем про сам разрыв. если он происходит то выполнение может и оборваться.

Comment: не забываем указывать max_exec~_time\max_memory_limit\оптимизировать сам скрипт. в случае с одним apache не замечал разрыва соединения, в случае когда nginx как прокси, не забываем про всякие proxy_send_timeout\и настройки не прерывать выполнение при разрыве соединения. к сожалению по памяти все настройки не помню, поэтому и написать мог названия тоже не правильно. Надеюсь чем то полезным удалось поделиться. а так советую писать асинхронные приложения, возможно используя другие технологии например nodejs, что увеличит скорость работы ваших парсеров

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Допустим, у вас есть компьютер с Windows. Вы можете открыть консоль и набрать там какие-нибудь команды. набрать [dir](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/dir.mspx?mfr=true) и  и получить список каталогов и файлов, скопировать файлы командой `copy`: `copy c:\a.txt d:\b.txt`

это консоль Windows.  Если на вашем компьютере установлен php, вы можете открыть консоль, набрать что-нибудь вроде `c:\lamp\php\bin\php -i` и увидеть настройки php.

Теперь представьте себе ваш хостинг. Операционная система, но не Windows, а Linux. Скорее всего у него нет графической оболочки. Единственный ваш способ общения с ним - через командную строку.

PHP CLI расшифровывается именно так: Command Line Interface. Интерфейс командной строки.

Если у вас есть ssh-доступ к вашему сайту, вы сможете им воспользоваться чтобы запускать php-скрипты в консоли, творить прочую консольную магию.

Заходите через ssh на ваш хост (ssh example_user@example.org), попадаете в [консоль](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F) и запускаете `php ваш_скрипт.php`

главные отличия между php-cli и "php через браузер":

1) php-cli выполняется с правами пользователя, который его запускает, php-через-браузер выполняется с правами "пользователя" веб-сервера.

2) Вы можете запустить что-нибудь в духе `sudo php someFile.php` и выполнить его с правами рута (самого главного пользователя в системе)

3) В php-cli по умолчанию нет ограничения по времени выполнения скрипта.

Если вы, допустим, подзабыли, как в принципе работает php - напомню. вашему серверу (apache, nginx) прилетает запрос - допустим на index.php - сервер посылает этот запрос демону php-fpm, который исполняет файл index.php, а результаты отправляет серверу, а сервер - вашему браузеру.

Это как если бы вам приходило письмо от друга с просьбой зайти в консоль, выполнить какой-то php-скрипт и прислать результат выполнения обратно.

Только гораздо быстрее.

В принципе, так интерпретаторы языков программирования и работают, на самом деле - через консоль.  Поддержка веб-сервера полностью факультативна.

Детали и настройки вы можете найти в мануале PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Найдите настройки SSH подключения вашего хостинга(как правило бесплатные хостинги не дают доступа, либо ограничивают его виртуальной консолью или php-cgi а не php-cli, если вам таки повезло и у вас есть доступ то подключитеcь через [Putty(Windows)](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html), или просто набрав ssh и параметры подключения в терминале Linux)

Дальше просто вызываете нужный скрипт уже из этой консоли.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
P.S. Рекомендую выносить скрипты подобные выше корня сайта, чтоб их не могли запустить из браузера а через консоль вы всё равно к ним достучитесь

Answer (score 0):

я использую php библиотеку для создании консольных приложений - PHP CLI APP

Примерный код будет выглядеть так

```
use Cli\Basic\Cli;

Cli::initialize([
    'script_file_name' => 'cli.php' // название файла
]);

Cli::handle('mySuperCommand', function () { // наша функция
    // много логики
    return "OK";
});

Cli::run(); // заводим
```

теперь можно вызывать свои команды:

```
php cli.php mySuperCommand
```

Создавать таким образом можно любое количество комманд.

https://github.com/AlexP007/cli#Russian - дока на русском