# Как скачиваемый файл сохранить в папку

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

Пишу парсер получения видео.Но немогу сохранить само полученное видео в нужную мне папку. Как исправить вот код.

```
foreach ($href as $key => $link) {
    $doc = file_get_html('https://example.com/'.$link);
    foreach($doc->find("#video source") as $el) {
        $video[]="https:".$el->src;  //с помощью simple html dom получаю ссылки на файл 
    }
}
//в итоге получаю
/* array(
"http:example/video1.mp4",
"http:example/video2.mp4",
"http:example/video3.mp4")
 */

$dirSubtitles=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/video/';
foreach ($video as $address) {
    $url  = $address;
    $path = $dirSubtitles;
    $fp = fopen($path."video", 'w');
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dirSubtitles=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/video/';
foreach ($video as $address) {
    copy($address,$dirSubtitles);
}
```

По поводу лимитов на время (и память). Нужно увеличивать `memory_limit` если будет тяжелый* процес. По поводу времени работы можно смело выставлять побольше если в системе один такой пользователь.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 9000);
ini_set('memory_limit', '200M');
```

Comment: работает,не подскажите а как всё-таки с помощью curl сохранить этот файл?

Comment: curl -O http://www.openss7.org/repos/tarballs/strx25-0.9.2.1.tar.bz2   /var/www/downloads

Answer (score 0):

```
$dirSubtitles = __DIR__ . '/video/';

foreach ($video as $address) {
    $url = $address;
    $path = $dirSubtitles;
    $name = pathinfo($address, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
    $fp = fopen($path . time() . $name, 'w');
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Comment: Ну как бы вполне может быть. Если вы качаете 100500 фильмов. Запускайте через CLI и уберите лимит на время

Comment: если вас не затруднит напишите как будет выглядеть

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/552700/216166

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
//This is the file where we save the    information
$fp = fopen(dirname(__FILE__) . '/localfile.tmp', 'w+');
//Here is the file we are downloading, replace spaces with %20
$ch = curl_init(str_replace(" ", "%20", $url));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
// write curl response to file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
// get curl response
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Можно глянуть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409462/downloading-a-large-file-using-curl)